# Run Package base program in command line

Tags: java

I have two class like so:

```
package one;

    public class Parent
    {

        protected String name = "hello world";
    }
```

And:

```
   package two;

        import one.Parent;

        class Child extends Parent 
        {
            public void testMethod()
            {
                System.out.println("name is " + name);
            }

            public static void main(String args[])
            {
                Child n = new Child();
                n.testMethod();
            }
        }
```

This classes are in the c\source folder

---

---

When I compile this classes in command line I get lot's of error I use more statement like so:

```
C:\source>javac -d Child.java
c:\sorce> javac *.java
```

Still I get many errors.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `Parent` should be located in `source/one/Parent.java` and `Child` should be located in `source/two/Child.java`. You then do `C:\source> javac -d bin two/Child.java` and run it with `C:\source\bin> javac two.Child`.

Comment: Sry when I compile like u said i recive this error message :javac : directory not found :bin

Comment: So do `mkdir bin` first then.

Answer (score 0):

I do a simple test. you can try again

the current directory structure.

```
--file
   --bin
   --Parent.java
   --Child.java
```

then execute the following cmd

```
cd bin
javac -d ./ ../Parent.java
javac -d ./ ../Child.java
java two.Child
```

The result is ok

if your code has a `package name`, you should use the option `-d`, in the compile process, `javac` will create directories according to the `package name`.

for `javac` tool

please refer

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/tooldocs/win32/javac.html

help that helped.